# How to do stuff during and after a child process

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, subprocess

I have a program that call to an subprogram. While the subprogram is running with Popen, I need the run button to be disable and the stop button to enable. However,  because Popen opens a new process, things that are suppose to print after the program has finish will print out right away. I tried adding `self.p.communicate()` after `Popen`, but the GUI will freeze until the subprogram finish running, hence the stop button will not work.
Here is my program:

```
def gui(QtGui.QWidget):
    ...
    self.runButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
    self.stopButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Stop')

    self.runButton.clicked.connect(self.run)
    self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.kill)

    self.runButton.setEnabled(True)
    self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)

def run(self):
    self.runButton.setEnabled(False)
    self.p = subprocess.Popen(sample.exe)

    #self.p.communicate()

    self.stopButton.setEnabled(True)   
    print "Finish running"  #without communicate() it will print out before .exe finish running

def kill(self):
    self.p.kill()
    self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
    print 'You have stop the program'
    self.runButton.setEnabled(True)
```

I'm using Window7, Python 2.7, pyqt4. I do not have to use subprocess, anything that open and able kill subprogram will be fine.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Tried using `QProcess` as dano suggested. I have added the following codes to my program:

```
def gui(QtCore.Widget):
    self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)    

def run(self):
    self.process.start(exe_path)
    self.process.started.connect(self.onstart)
    self.process.finished.connect(self.onfinish)
    self.runButton.setEnabled(False)

    #self.p = subprocess.Popen(sample.exe)   #removed
    #self.p.communicate()                    #removed

def onstart (self):
    self.stopButton.setEnabled(True)     
    self.runButton.setEnabled(False)
    print "Started\n"

def onfinish (self):
    self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)     
    self.runButton.setEnabled(True)
    print "Finish running\n"

def kill(self):
    self.process.kill()
    #self.p.kill()                           #removed
```

Here is the output:

Click "Run" (output when subprogram finish running)

```
Finish running
```

Click "Run" second time

```
Started
```

Click "Stop"

```
Finish running
Finish running
```

Click "Run" third time

```
Started
Started
```

Click "Stop"

```
Finish running
Finish running
Finish running
```

Something happened here.

Comment: To clarify, you want your program to run in the background, and you want its stdout to be printed, but only after the program has finished running?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question. If you mean that my program (GUI)'s stdout printed after the executable(someone else's) finish running. Then yes.

Comment: Ah, so you don't care about the stdout of the subprocess. You just don't want "Finish running" to be printed until the subprocess is actually completed, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Looks like you can do this using `QProcess`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804325/qt-qpushbutton-is-blocked-by-child-process. If that answers your question, I'll mark it as a dupe.

Comment: How do you kill the `QProcess`? Also, out of curiosity, if I do need real time stdout from the subprogram, would `QProcess` still work?

Comment: According to [the docs for `QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#terminate), it has a `terminate()` method you can use to kill the process. I've never used a `QProcess` before, but it looks like you can use the `readChannel()` method to get an object that will let you call things like `readLine`, etc. on it, which would give you real-time stdout.

Comment: You should not connect your signals to slots when the "run" button is clicked, but when the `QProcess` is instantiated. As it stands now, when you click "Run" the second time, it is connecting the signals again, and so the methods `onStart` and `onFinish` are connected multiple times and are thus running multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p = subprocess.Popen(exe)` does not wait for `exe` to finish -- it returns as soon as `exe` is started.

`p.communicate()` does wait for the child process to end and therefore it blocks your GUI thread (GUI freezes until the subprocess exits).

To avoid blocking the GUI, you could check whether `p.poll()` returns `None` to find out whether `p` process is still running. Usually a GUI framework provides a way to set up periodic callbacks (e.g., QTimer for Qt) -- you can call `p.poll()` there. 
Or put the blocking call (such as `p.wait()`) into a background thread and  notify GUI thread on completion (emit signal, generate an event).

QProcess [suggested by @dano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220197/how-to-do-stuff-during-and-after-a-child-process#comment44804834_28220197) already has the notification mechanism built-in (`finished` signal).

As [@three_pineapples said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220197/how-to-do-stuff-during-and-after-a-child-process#comment44814595_28220197): do not connect the same signal multiple times if you don't want the callbacks to be called multiple times. There is no point in your case to call `.start()` on the same process instance more than once:

```
def run(self):
    self.runButton.setEnabled(False) # call it first because 
                                     # processes are not started instantly
    self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self) 
    self.process.started.connect(self.onstart) # connect "start" signal
    self.process.finished.connect(self.onfinish)
    self.process.start(exe_path, args) # then start
```